# Openshift - error streaming logs from build pod

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

I am testing out Openshift using the free starter account. I deployed their nodejs-mongo-persistent example. It is using starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com.

The original code comes from https://github.com/sclorg/nodejs-ex

I tried to separate the mongo code and routes from the server.js file and it works fine locally. When I try to build it online I get the following error

> error streaming logs from build pod: mikesmith/nodejs-mongo-persistent-6-build container: , container "sti-build" in pod "nodejs-mongo-persistent-6-build" is not available

The only other thing I did was update chai and mocha due to warnings.

The problem code is here *link deleted as it no longer exists*

I searched Google as well as stackoverflow and the only similar questions don't seem to have any resolution.

I am not convinced it is a problem with the code since I have had problems with Openshift since I started using it. It took 6 deploys to get the database deployed from the example code with no changes.

Maybe Openshift has a lot of issues that someday might be worked out and I should search for another option. It seemed to be a good free option for testing/learning since Heroku's free option has it's issues like sleeping after 30 mins of inactivity etc.

If anyone can let me know if this is a code issue or an Openshift issue that would be great. Thank you.

Update based on comment: Understood. It is not really possible to simplify this problem enough and is therefore an unanswerable question. Sorry to waste your time. Also, I believe now that it is a code issue so I will restart from scratch and see what happens.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer to this that may save someone else some time. I was hoping there was a quick answer to save hours of experimentation. It turns out that the problem was updating mocha. I unfortunately did not find any good documentation on the error message but I experimented with different versions of mocha.

Updating to mocha version 3.5.3 works. I only tried versions 4.1.0 and 5.1.1 above that and both fail. Version 3.5.3 shows a critical severity vulnerability in the growl dependency. The vulnerabilities is what started me on this journey to begin with.

Updating chai to 4.1.2, chai-http to 4.0.0 and object-assign to 4.1.1 did not cause any issue.

Note: There are likely many things that can cause that error message but this was what caused it for me.

Moral of the story: Careful updating packages even if it is just the testing framework. It can cause more than just failing tests. The 2 tests included actually still showed as passing on Openshift.